# Connection Refused While connecting Host Through Net::FTP in perl

Tags: perl, ftp, connection, connection-refused

When  I run below code through perl script at that time I always get error like connection refused so please any body can suggest to solve this issue.

ftp_check.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;


my $host = '111.118.248.24';

#-- connect to ftp server
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host, Debug => 1) or die "Error connecting to $host: $!";
```

Message getting like "Error connecting to 111.118.248.24: Connection refused at ftp_check.pl line 10."

Comment: Sounds like the remote host at `111.118.248.24` is not running an FTP server, or FTP access is blocked by your firewall. Can you ftp to that server from the command line? What command do you type?

Answer (score 0):

i supposed you server works properly, just for the case you can make some pings on it. Anyway, do you have a possibility to run in a terminal ( with ssh or some client like putty if you are a windows user ) following commands:

`netstat -tulpena | grep -i LIST <<ENTER>>`

Now you can see is there a FTP-Server which is running in a listener mode.

The second step would be to to use some ftp-client to check, that you can connect with your FTP-Server properly, just to see is there a firewall-rule in between, actually you could run "iptables -L" on a server to, but it will be easier just to use some ftp-client to make a verification of your ftp-server.

An other suggestion would be to use something more secure 
and not the net::ftp-module. Perl has nice CPAN-Modules for SFTP (Net::FTP).

Cheers.